# DrawerLayout and ImageView both implementing onTouchListener

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, ontouchlistener, drawerlayout, ontouch

I'm moving to a `DrawerLayout` however the said layout also contains an `ImageView` on top of which an `onTouchListener` is implemented for zoom/rotate functionality.

The problem is drawers own touch handler crashes my application when I try any of the `ImageView` functions.

I have tried setting `drawerLayout.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);` but this did not really help.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- map container -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/map_layout"
        android:background="@color/divider_color"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <!-- navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/divider_color"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="@color/button_label"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Exception:

```
  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
            at android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper.shouldInterceptTouchEvent(ViewDragHelper.java:1014)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent(DrawerLayout.java:1140)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1859)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2072)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1519)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2467)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2020)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8017)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3977)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3856)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3416)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3466)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3435)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3542)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3443)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3599)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3416)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3466)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3435)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3443)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3416)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5565)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5545)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5516)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5645)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:5618)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5664)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:542)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5212)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I have the same stacktrace. Did you find the answer?

Comment: @AntonGolovin Yes I did I'll post it as an answer give me few min.

Comment: @AntonGolovin Posted.

Comment: Please check [this updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36004008/2826147)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only short and working solution I found was to extend the DrawerLayout and override the `onTouchEvent` and `onInterceptTouchEvent` methods.

So I first start by creating my own custom `Layout` based on `DrawerLayout` I called it NavigationDrawer:

**NavigationDrawer.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class NavigationDrawer extends DrawerLayout {

    private ListView menu;

    public NavigationDrawer(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NavigationDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    public NavigationDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int disp) {
        super(context, attributeSet, disp);
    }

    public void addMenu(ListView menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
    }

    /**
     * Override the method to correct the detection region for the navigation layout open/close case.
     * @param ev Motion event descriptor
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        super.onTouchEvent(ev);

        if (ev.getX() > 30 && ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (isDrawerOpen(menu) || isDrawerVisible(menu)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Override the method to catch ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception thrown in conflict between
     * the two touch listeners.
     * @param ev Motion event descriptor
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        try {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The layout to create it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<...views.NavigationDrawer
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

       <!-- My own content in here most likely you will want swappable fragment. -->

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- List of our menu options -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/divider_color"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="@color/button_label"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</...views.NavigationDrawer>
```

Also need the `ListView` item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/main_title"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:textColor="@color/checkbox_label" />
```

And then to create everything:

```
    // Navigation menu
    private NavigationDrawer menuLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle menuToggle;
    private ListView menu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_navigator);

        // Setup the navigation drawer layout
        String[] menuOptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_options);
        menu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu);
        menuLayout = (NavigationDrawer) findViewById(R.id.content_layout);
        menuLayout.addMenu(menu);
        menuLayout.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

        // Populate the menu with options
        menu.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.layout_navigator_item, menuOptions));
        menu.setOnItemClickListener(new MenuItemSelected());

        menuToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, menuLayout, null, R.string.open, R.string.closed) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }
        };
}
```

Comment: I found another solution that is might be helpful https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60464#c5